# cordova css transition become slower after few clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have a list in my html page. There is a button that allow user to add item into the list. Everytime user adds a new item, it will have animation effect let new item move from left to center

```
 $("#addNewItem").on("click",function(){
    $('.List').append('<li class="listLeft listTransition"></li>');
    setTimeout(function () {
               $('#newLi').removeClass('listLeft');
               $('#newLi'.addClass('listCenter');
               }, 10);
});
//css class
    .listLeft{
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 1px);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
    .listCenter{
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .listTransition{
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
```

It work well for first few attempts, after I clicked more than 3 times, the transition will become slower. It will take 2 -3 seconds to wait for item animates into center. After I tried more than 7 times, it will become even slower. This is nothing related to list size, because if I restart and reopen the app, by having larger list items, the first few attempts will always have good performance. After 4th clicks, the transition become slower. 
 Previously I was using jquery .animate('left', 1000) to do transition. I thought this is the reason that cause slow transition, so i switch to hardware accelerated by using webkit transition, but eventually the results are same, so I guess there is nothing related to it. 
During testing, I put an alert('testing') before the $('.List').append(), I noticed this accidentally solved my problem, maybe the alert() will clear some cache or do something, but I don't know. Unfortunately this is not allowed to prompt alert box, so it cannot be solution for me, I tried to use bootstrap modal dialog to do the same thing, but it did not give me the smooth transition as well after 4th clicks

 
I wish to know what is the magic inside alert() that can solve my problem, then I can duplicate similar logic of code without calling alert(). If would be nice if I can know root cause as well

Comment: Provide all relevant code, MCVE. You talk about a click handler, which is?! BTW, provide your code as in use, this is clearly not the code you are using: `$('newLi'.addClass('listCenter');`

Comment: @A.Wolff, thank you, edited the question

Comment: Your code has still some typos. But i don't see anything wrong with your handler. Are you nesting it inside other event?

Comment: @A.Wolff, nope, the button will directly trigger click event. This only happen on cordova/phonegap or any webview app. I also curious why it will become slower after few clicks, but the alert() solved my problem. I dont know what is alert() doing in the background, perhaps it might clean something that cause slow performance

Comment: alert() is modal, it blocks any further javscript code to be executed until it is closed. That could explain it if you were binding multiple times same handler. I'm not cordova developper but i suspect you call your binding snippet more than once but for sure, i don't know... :( Just wondering, why are you using a timeout?

Comment: @A.Wolff, Without timeout and directly call .removeClass('listLeft'); .addClas('listCenter'), it cannot achieve the animation effect, The problem also solved if I remove code for removeClass and addClass, but it would remove animation effect as well.

Comment: Have you got same issue using: `$('.List').append('<li class="listLeft listTransition"></li>'); $('#newLi').hide().show(0).toggleClass('listLeft listCenter');` ?  (instead of timeout)  I don't see why timeout would cause an issue but who knows... And still, would be more helpful if you provide jsFiddle replicating issue

Comment: Awesome!!, this solved my problem that I have been sucked for few days. Could you answer this question then I can mark it as correct. I guess jsFiddle would not have same result, it just work well on normal web broswer.

Comment: I don't want to reply to question which i don't really have answer... :)  Just the `.hide().show(0)` part force a UI repaint on webkit based browser but still i don't understand why the timeout was a issue in your code. I hope someone else get an answer?! I suggest you to let this question open